# SilverStripe is not displaying image

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am learning SilverStripe by developing a simple project. Now I am having a problem with displaying images in the template file.

This is my BlogPage.php

```
<?php

namespace {

    use SilverStripe\AssetAdmin\Forms\UploadField;
    use SilverStripe\Assets\Image;

    class BlogPage extends Page
    {
        private static $can_be_root = false;

        private static $has_one = [
            'Banner' => Image::class,
        ];

        public function getCMSFields()
        {
            $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Attachments', $banner = UploadField::create('Banner'));
            $banner->setFolderName('banners');

            return $fields;
        }
    }
}
```

I can upload the banner image inside the Admin panel. I am trying to display the image in the BlogPage.ss like this.

```
<% with $Banner.ScaleWidth(750) %>
    <img class="my-custom-class" src="$URL" alt="" width="$Width" height="$Height" />
<% end_with %>
```

But it is not displaying anything. When I inspect the URL in the console, it is (unknown). What is wrong? How can I display the image?

### Edit

I edited question according to Robbie's answer below.

This is my BlogPage.php

```
<?php

namespace {

    use SilverStripe\AssetAdmin\Forms\UploadField;
    use SilverStripe\Assets\Image;

    class BlogPage extends Page
    {
        private static $can_be_root = false;

        private static $has_one = [
            'Banner' => Image::class,
        ];

        private static $owns = [
            'Banner',
        ];

        public function getCMSFields()
        {
            $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Attachments', $banner = UploadField::create('Banner'));
            $banner->setFolderName('banners');

            return $fields;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my BlogPage.ss

```
<% with $Banner %>
    <img class="my-custom-class" src="$URL" alt="" width="$Width" height="$Height" />
<% end_with %>

<h3>$Title</h3>

$Content
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ScaleWidth()` method will actually return a full image tag for you, so you don't need to specify width, height, etc. You can do this:

```
$Banner.ScaleWidth(750)
```

If you want to render the image yourself, you can remove the `.ScaleWidth()` part. The `with` structure changes the scope from the current scope (presumably a page) to the `$Banner` relationship or model returned by `Banner()` or `getBanner()` in your model or controller, so then variable calls within it are within the banner's scope.

```
<% with $Banner %>
    <img class="my-custom-class" src="$URL" alt="" width="$Width" height="$Height" />
<% end_with %>
```

Also, note that files and images are versioned by default in SilverStripe 4. This means that when you publish your page, the image you've attached to it won't be automatically published and won't show up on your frontend. You can tell SilverStripe that your page "owns" the images you upload, which will auto-publish them with the page:

```
// On your page:
private static $owns = ['Banner'];
```

Comment: Hi there, you'll need to be more descriptive for me to help you further. I tested your code in a fresh project to be sure. Ensure you have published your image (see my last note).

Comment: Did you flush your cache after you added the `$owns` API, OR did you go and publish the image that's attached to your page? Your code works fine for me

Comment: If you could provide some more information that'd be nice - "it doesn't work" isn't particularly helpful. You could try `$Banner.Debug` in your template to see what the object looks like, whether it has an ID, etc

Comment: What I have found with SS4 is that if you upload an image, then release that you haven't added the `private static $owns = ['Banner'];` code, you update the code, then try and save the the image again, it doesn't work. What does work is uploading another image.

Comment: Hi @GavinBruce. You are right. Uploading new image works. Wired. Cheers man.

Comment: @GavinBruce +1 you are right. what I usually do is to force publishing the image after saving like this 

`if($this->BannerID){$this>Banner()->doPublish();}`
Remember this is only a fix and it only works if the assets are versioned.